# Prove that the set of palindromes are not regular languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

Let L = {w| w ∈ {a,b,c} * is palindrome}
Could someone explain me how to prove that L is not regular, because all answers I've found are done with 2 symbols(a,b), and I'd need to prove it with 3.

Comment: If it doesn't work with $2$ symbols, it cannot work for $3$ symbols because we can omit $c$ and have a string with $2$ symbols.

Comment: ok, so how would you prove that L is not regular?

Comment: Please show the disproof with $2$ symbols, maybe I can extend it to $3$ symbols.

Comment: [Disproof](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~torng/360Book/RegLang/Pumping/#PALINDROME-LONG)

Comment: @CaptainSpock: The same argument can be used here without any changes.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott if s="cabac", how would you prove that L is not regular?

Comment: @CaptainSpock: You don’t use $cabac$; if $p$ is the pumping length, use $a^pba^p$.